# Adding clicked on checkBoxes text to a parent span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When someone clicks on a checkbox i want to add or remove the text from the span underneath the category where they clicked on.

```
<div class="trigger">Artist</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="Offset">
      <label class="label">Offset
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="takeOff">
      <label class="label">takeOff
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="trigger">Album</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture">
      <label class="label">culture
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture2">
      <label class="label">culture2
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
let text;

$('.refinement').on('click', function(event) {
    text= event.target.getAttribute('name')
    console.log(text)
});
```

So far i figured out how to get the text, but i need help figuring out how to append it to the parent span above it

Comment: $('.refinements).append(text); or maybe $('.refinements).html(text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments inline (fyi: you aren't using the `label` element correctly):

```js
let text;

$('.refinement').on('click', function(event) {   
    // Find the ancestor UL that begins the list and then
    // get the sibling just prior to it. Also, "this" will
    // access the object that the event handler was set on
    // and you can get attributes of it via direct properties.
    this.closest("ul.filters").previousSibling.textContent = this.name;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger">Artist</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <label class="label">
        <!-- Labels must either use the "for" attribute to
             associate themselves with an element by its ID or
             they should contain the element they are for.
             This provides the appropriate accessibility as you can
             then click on the label or the control to activate the event.
        -->
        <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="Offset">Offset
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <label class="label">
        <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="takeOff">
        takeOff
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="trigger">Album</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <label class="label">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture">culture
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <label class="label">
            <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture2">culture2
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve correctly but this is to replace the text underneath :

```
$('.refinement').on('click', function(event) {
    newText="";
    $(event.target).parent().find(".label").html(newText)
});
```

and this is to copy the text beneath the checkbox

```
$('.refinement').on('click', function(event) {
    oldText=$(event.target).parent().find(".label").html()
    $(event.target).parent().find(".first-span").remove()
    $(event.target).parent().prepend("<span class='first-span'>"+oldText+"</span>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
// listener on checkbox with class "refinement"
$('.refinement').on('change', function() {
  // getting checkbox name
  const checkboxName = $(this).attr('name')

  // getting span element over his ul parent
  const $spanAssigned = $(this).closest('ul').prev()
  
  // if checkbox is checked append template with checkboxName
  // inside of $spanAssigned element
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    const template = `<span>${checkboxName} <span>`
    
    $spanAssigned.append(template)
  } 
  // if checkbox isn't checked find & remove from $spanAssigned element
  else {
    $spanAssigned.find(`span:contains(${checkboxName})`).remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger">Artist</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="Offset">
      <label class="label">Offset
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="takeOff">
      <label class="label">takeOff
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="trigger">Album</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture">
      <label class="label">culture
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture2">
      <label class="label">culture2
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if the span is not directly above the <ul> how would i target it?

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood your problem so I have tried to resolve your problem.
My demo code URL is given below:

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="abc">
<div class="trigger">Artist</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="Offset">
      <label class="label">Offset
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="takeOff">
      <label class="label">takeOff
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="abc">
<div class="trigger">Album</div>
<span class="refinements"></span>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture">
      <label class="label">culture
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <div class = "checkBox">
      <input class = "refinement" type="checkbox" name="culture2">
      <label class="label">culture2
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Jabascript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.refinement',function(){
    var p = $(this).parents('.abc').first();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      p.find('.refinements').text($(this).attr('name'));
    } else {
      p.find('.refinements').text('');
    }
  })
});
```

Please try this.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't ever link to your code as links can die over time making your answer meaningless. Always insert your code right in your answer as a code snippet. Additionally, answers should explain what the problem is and how your code solves it.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for telling me...I will update my answer here.